# Here, I am getting trouble while i put data its not accessed by Firestore Database, plese tell where is the problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am getting error and its not responding what I expecting.
please tell where is problem.
while I tried to upload my data like name, email and expect to be uploaded to firebase database but it didn't it, and I got some error.
Please tell where is prob.

```
import React from 'react'
import Add from "../image/logo1.png"
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth , db, storage} from "../firebase";
import { useState } from 'react';
import {  ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 


const Register = () => {
  const [err, setErr] = useState(false)
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // console.log(e.target[0].value);
    const displayName = e.target[0].value;
    const email = e.target[1].value;
    const password = e.target[2].value;
    const file = e.target[3].files[0];

    try {
      const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);


      const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

      uploadTask.on('state_changed',
    
        (error) => {
          setErr(true);
        },
        () => {`enter code here`
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async(downloadURL) => {
            await updateProfile(res.user,{
              displayName,
              photoURL:downloadURL,
            })
            await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid),{
              uid: res.user.uid,
              displayName,
              email,
              photoURL: downloadURL,
            });
          });
        }
      );



    } catch (err) {
      setErr(true);
    }


  }

  return (
    <div className='formContainer'>
      <div className='formWrapper'>
        <span className="logo">Ut Chat</span>
        <span className="title">Register</span>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder='display name' />
          <input type="email" placeholder="email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
          <input style={{ display: "none" }} type="file" id='file' />
          <label htmlFor="file">
            <img src={Add} alt="" />
            <span>add an image</span>
          </label>
          <button>sign up</button>
          {err && <span>something went wrong</span>}
        </form>
        <p>Do you have an account? Login</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Register
```

Answer (score 0):

The first function in `uploadTask.on()` is an observer that triggers on upload progress but here you have error handle defined as first. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  (snap) => console.log("received update"),
  (error) => {
    setErr(true);
  },
  async () => {
    `enter code here`
    const fileUrl = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
    await updateProfile(res.user, {
      displayName,
      photoURL: fileUrl,
    })
    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid), {
      uid: res.user.uid,
      displayName,
      email,
      photoURL: fileUrl,
    });
  });
```